# Continually replace numbers in hat by absolute value of difference; what's the distribution of the final number in the hat?

Tags: probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics

I was in a class recently, and was asked the following question:

> Imagine you have a hat containing pieces of paper numbered from $1$ to $N$. You remove two pieces of paper at random from the hat, and replace them with the absolute value of the difference between the two numbers. You repeat this process until there is one piece of paper remaining. What can you tell about the final piece of paper?

When we draw two pieces of paper, we either reduce the amount of odd numbers by two (if two odd numbers are drawn, resulting in an even number), or the amount of odd numbers stays the same. Thus we can deduce that the final piece of paper will be even if the starting amount of odd numbers is even, and odd if the starting amount of odd numbers is odd.

As an extension to this, I wondered what the probability distribution of the final piece of paper in the hat is, i.e. for $X$ being the random variable representing the final piece of paper in the hat, what is $P_N(X = k)$, for $k \in \{0, 1, ..., N\}$?

In order to find some sort of pattern, I wrote the following Python program to simulate the game for any N, and return an array of the amount of times each number was left in the hat.

```
# Import necessary dependencies
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm

def finalPiece(n):
    ''' 
    Pick pieces out of the hat randomly, replace with the absolute value
    of the difference and return the final number left.
    '''
    numberOfPieces = n
    piecesInHat = list(range(1, n+1))
    while numberOfPieces > 1:
        # Pick random piece of paper
        choice1Index = np.random.randint(0, numberOfPieces)
        choice2Index = np.random.randint(0, numberOfPieces-1)
        # Remove pieces of paper from hat
        choice1 = piecesInHat.pop(choice1Index)
        choice2 = piecesInHat.pop(choice2Index)
        # Replace with new number
        piecesInHat.append(abs(choice1-choice2))
        numberOfPieces = numberOfPieces - 1
    return piecesInHat[0]

def experiment(numbersInHat, numberOfTrials, plot=False, save=False):
    ''' 
    Repeat the finalPiece function and count how many times each number
    is left in the hat. Plot the result if plot == True. Save the results
    array if save == True.
    '''
    results = np.zeros(numbersInHat+1, dtype=int)
    # Count number of times each number is left in the hat, with progress bar
    for _ in tqdm(range(numberOfTrials)):
        results[finalPiece(numbersInHat)] += 1
    # Make a plot if it is desired
    if plot:
        x = np.linspace(0, numbersInHat, numbersInHat+1, dtype=int)
        plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=800)
        plt.xlabel('Final Number in the Hat')
        plt.ylabel('Percentage of Experiments')
        plt.title('Hat Numbers Experiment: ' + str(numbersInHat) + ', ' + str(numberOfTrials))
        plt.bar(x, results*100/numberOfTrials)
        plt.savefig('bar graph ' + str(numbersInHat) + ' ' + str(numberOfTrials) + '.png')
        #plt.show()
    # Save results to file if it is desired
    if save:
        np.savetxt('counts ' + str(numbersInHat) + ' ' + str(numberOfTrials) +'.txt', results, fmt='%d')
    # Return results array (counts of experiments)
    return results
```

This shows the probability decreasing as $k$ increases (with $k$ of appropriate parity, and $k\neq 0$), but I still haven't been able to work out what the distribution actually is. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Edit: To clarify, I am seeking an explicit formula for $P_N(X = k)$ if possible. Using the code above, I have already explored the distribution stochastically for large $N$.

Comment: If I understand your code, you might "select" the same piece of paper *twice* on any given iteration.... right?

Comment: I don't believe so — when we use pop(choice1Index), the element at choice1Index is removed from the list, and the elements after it are "shifted" along by 1, so there is no "gap" in the list. Therefore, even if choice2Index was to be equal to choice1Index, it would not select the same piece of paper twice.

Comment: But don't you select the indices *before* you remove the pieces of paper?

Comment: Yes, but this shouldn't matter (you could move the line choice2Index = ... to be directly after the first removal from the hat, if you wished). Since the pop() method alters the list it acts upon, when we use pop(choice1Index), it's as if we have a new list, with the element at choice1Index removed. So by the time we use pop(choice2Index), the "hat" has already had the piece of paper removed. For example, if we have list=[1,2,3,4] and do choice=list.pop(1), choice would be equal to 2, and list would now be equal to [1,3,4]. Doing choice=list.pop(1) again would leave list equal to [1,4].

Answer (score 2):

The number of ways the game can go is $\prod_{i=2}^n \binom{i}{2}=\dfrac{n!(n-1)!}{2^{n-1}}$ (see https://oeis.org/A006472). I wrote my own code in [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/) to just go down every branch to find the exact answers for starting numbers of slips up to 9 (10 takes longer than I'd like to wait using my naive method:

```
del[list_, n_] := del[list, n] = DeleteCases[list, n, 1, 1]; 
delpair[list_, pair_] := 
 delpair[list, pair] = del[del[list, pair[[1]]], pair[[2]]]; 
play[x_] := 
 play[x] = 
  Flatten[If[Length[x] == 1, x, 
    Map[play[Append[delpair[x, Sort@#], Abs[#[[1]] - #[[2]]]]] &, 
     Subsets[x, {2}]]]]; denom[n_] := n!*(n - 1)!/2^(n - 1); 
numer[n_] := Counts[Sort[play[Range[n]]]]; 
dist[n_] := numer[n]/denom[n]; Do[Print[i, ": ", dist[i]], {i, 9}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDfS8MwEH7vX3FbQVQqo31zUnBsCIKCuMcQR2bPLdBeS5PCZOxvr5ekUSEPX@677wfXKHvERln9qcaxwlrU2thdBrSTsCwhTnggoYQN1mhxrQyaOM4g5ycfIOHdTuk@OjgcTBL4TwXGuTnzvwC/IHIpZcQFY/btavUtTtEq/Jw8AXiqlbVI4vlLvCAd7NEzpat0ytwCwKvqhNesug6pErEK89u2t48px632RqQ@G@4gDcGMryYL2A57g9Y4zbm4SF@rQmobMZ2JZrfXxNr8ZrYoPibI1WlosI9L63YgNnGpodG7ogMKCn5JxVf49Qs6uZhSmN@04q3XZIXOYL6EeQZeoN25zjy7v8hx/AE)

The results are as follows:
$$\begin{matrix}0&1\\0&1\\\dfrac23&0&\dfrac13\\\dfrac49&0&\dfrac49&0&\dfrac19\\0&\dfrac{19}{30}&0&\dfrac{29}{90}&0&\dfrac{2}{45}\\0&\dfrac{269}{450}&0&\dfrac{212}{675}&0&\dfrac{119}{1350}\\\dfrac{1444}{4725}&0&\dfrac{5881}{14175}&0&\dfrac{88}{405}&0&\dfrac{14}{225}\\\dfrac{57073}{198450}&0&\dfrac{4232}{11025}&0&\dfrac{22111}{99225}&0&\dfrac{6131}{66150}&0&\dfrac{431}{33075}\\0&\dfrac{3323063}{7144200}&0&\dfrac{2134871}{7144200}&0&\dfrac{286901}{1786050}&0&\dfrac{156479}{2381400}&0&\dfrac{923}{95256}\end{matrix}$$

I checked the numerators of the unsimplified fractions in the OEIS and found they didn't all appear in the OEIS at all.

As requested, here are the means and variances (`Mean[play[Range[i]]]` and `Variance[play[Range[i]]]`):

Means: $1,1,\dfrac23\approx0.67,\dfrac43\approx1.33,\dfrac{82}{45}\approx1.82,\dfrac{1337}{675}\approx1.98,\dfrac{29374}{14175}\approx2.07,\dfrac{230143}{99225}\approx2.32,\dfrac{322913}{119070}\approx2.71$

Variances:$0,0,\dfrac43\approx1.33,\dfrac{32}{17}\approx1.88,\dfrac{10724}{8055}\approx1.33,\dfrac{3107024}{1821825}\approx1.71,\dfrac{2476997696}{803708325}\approx3.08,\dfrac{47158935632}{12117654675}\approx3.89,\dfrac{866608104176}{226842634431}\approx3.82$

Comment: You can delete two distinct elements far more efficiently with `RandomChoice[list,2]`.  Why not calculate the average and variance for each $n$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, RandomChoice would give me a random pair, right? I want to consider all pairs, not do a Monte Carlo simulation. I can add the averages and variances, sure.

Comment: A yes.  But if you want to explore the results for large $n$, I suspect you'll want a stochastic, not exhaustive, sampling of numbers.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I interpreted the question's "In order to find some sort of pattern" as looking for an explicit formula. If that's the case, then I think a stochastic sampling is less likely to be helpful in finding something. But you may disagree, and/or I may have misinterpreted the intent of the poster.